# building webrtc APM error "NEON support not enabled" in Qt on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, webrtc, apm

building webrtc apm in Qt on Mac ,bug it show #error "NEON support not enabled" in arm_neon.h

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue building WebRTC with command lines.

Just ensure the env variables are correct

```
export GYP_DEFINES="OS=ios target_arch=arm64"
export GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS="output_dir=out_ios64"
```

Execute the command line before each build (even after the same build)

```
webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc
```

I haven't looked deeper to find the reason.

HTH,

Michael